# How to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} ( \ln(1 - \sin x) + x)/x^2$ without using l'Hôpital?

Tags: limits, logarithms, limits-without-lhopital

How to evaluate
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1 - \sin x) + x} {x^2}$$
without using l'Hôpital?
I am not able to substitute the right infinitesimal. Is there a substitute?

#### Background

1. We have yet not done Taylor expansions.
2. I know that $\ln$ around 1 tends to 0 and $\sin$ around 0 tends to 0.

Comment: **Every** limit can be computed without using L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: @Did No different solutions? We have yet not done Taylor. Not for now.

Comment: What methods have you learned? What do you know about $\ln$ around $1$ and $\sin$ around $0$?

Comment: Notable limits, and something about infinitesimal and infinite principles(substitution and elimination). I know that ln around 1 tends to 0 and sin around 0 tendes to 0.

Comment: That is good. But I an sorry I do not yet fully understand what you know, and I think you need to know somthing more than this to do that excercice. Do you know something that resembles form $\sin x$ is $x - x^3/3!+ O(x^5)$? Or $\ln (1-x)$ is $-x -x^2/2+ O(x^3)$ where possibly $x$ is an infinitessimal?

Comment: Out of curiosity O(x) is order? I think still have much to learn XD Can you link me some material about this? Thanks for everything ^_^

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, here $O(x^3)$  means that the other terms are at least of order $3$ in $x$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation especially the section Infinitesimal asymptotics there.

Answer (score 1):

If Series Expansion is allowed,

$$\ln(1-\sin x)=-\sin x-\frac{\sin^2 x}2-O(\sin^3x)$$

Again,$$\sin x=x-O(x^3)$$

Comment: @DrunkCat, An almost exhaustive list of Series Expansion is available here : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesExpansion.html

Answer (score 1):

You might use Taylor series expansions:
$$\begin{align} \sin x &= x+O(x^3)\\
\ln(1+x)&= x-\frac12x^2+O(x^3)\\
\implies \ln(1-\sin x)+x&=\frac12x^2+O(x^3)\\
\implies \frac{\ln(1-\sin x)+x}{x^2}&=\frac12+O(x)\end{align}$$

Comment: You got the sign wrong. When you plug $(-\sin x)$ into the quadratic term its sign will not change.

Comment: No different solutions? We have yet not done Taylor. Not for now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the two limits (in addition to the standard limits like $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1$): $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x - \log(1 + x)}{x^{2}} = \frac{1}{2},\,\,\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x - \sin x}{x^{2}} = 0$$ The first of these limits is bit difficult to handle without L'Hospital's Rule and has been calculated in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/914642/72031). The second limit is solved in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921621/72031).

Note that if we put $x = -t$ in the first limit we get $$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\log(1 - t) + t}{t^{2}} = -\frac{1}{2}$$ and we will use this form here. We proceed as follows $$\begin{aligned}L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 - \sin x) + x}{x^{2}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 - \sin x) + \sin x + x - \sin x}{x^{2}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 - \sin x) + \sin x}{x^{2}} + \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x - \sin x}{x^{2}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 - \sin x) + \sin x}{\sin^{2}x}\cdot\frac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 - \sin x) + \sin x}{\sin^{2}x}\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\log(1 - t) + t}{t^{2}}\text{ (putting }t = \sin x)\\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $\ln (1 - x) = -\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x^n/n$, near $0$. 
So, $$\ln (1 - \sin  x) = -\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (\sin x)^n/n = - x -x^2/2 + O(x^3).$$

I guess you can finish from there.