# Limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} x-x^{2}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

Give me please a hint, how to find

$$\underset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}x-x^{2}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

I tried to use substitution $h = \frac{1}{x}$ and, then, apply L'Hopital's rule, but it went worse.

Comment: In my opinion, using the Taylor expansion of the logarithm is the easiest way here.

Comment: See also
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914072/finding-the-limit-lim-x-to-inftyx-x2-log11-x-in-a-elementary-way and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1998703/how-do-i-determine-lim-x-to-infty-leftx-x2-log-left1-1-x-right-r and
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2003300/limits-and-exponential

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\log (1+y) = y - y^2/2 + O(y^3).$$
$$\log (1+1/x) = x^{-1} - x^{-2}/2 + O(x^{-3}).$$
$$x^2 \log (1+1/x) = x - 1/2 + O(x^{-1}).$$
$$x^2 \log (1+1/x) -x =  - 1/2 + O(x^{-1}).$$
Done!

Comment: I never thought to use Taylor series, nice method Mark!

Comment: How did you determine that expanding up to 2 terms would be enough?

Comment: well there's only 1 term to cancel so develop 1 further to get the lead thing left. More generally, try 2 and if that doesn't work do 3...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I was not right just now.

You can do substitution as you mentioned.

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1}{h}-\frac{1}{h^2}\ln{(1+h)}\right)\\
=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{h-\ln{(1+h)}}{h^2}\\
=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\frac{1}{1+h}}{2h}\\
=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{h}{2h(1+h)}$$

And you can continue from here. From line 2 to 3 I used L'Hospital's rule.