# Solving $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$ = \lim_{x\to0} (\frac{e^x-1}{x} * \frac{1}{x}) -\frac{x}{x^2}$$ 
$$ = \lim_{x\to0} (\frac{e^x-1}{x} * \frac{1}{x}) -\frac{x}{x^2}$$ 
$$ = 1 * \lim_{x\to0} \frac{1}{x} -\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}$$
$$ = \infty -\infty$$

How do I actually solve this without using L'Hospital. I'm just looking for a hint, not a concrete answer.

Comment: Do you know the taylor series of $e^x$?

Comment: Taylor would help

Comment: L'Hopital twice. you should find 1/2.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Tag: ([tag:limits-without-lhopital]) and the OP also asks that the limit be done w/o L'H.

Comment: Your approach has a flaw when you move from second line to third line. This is not allowed.

Answer (score 7):

### No series or L'Hospital's required!  "DISCLAIMER": This is not a hint.

Consider $x\mapsto-x$ to get

$$L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{-x}-1+x}{x^2}$$

Add these together to get

$$\begin{align}2L&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x+e^{-x}-2}{x^2}\tag1\\&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2})^2}{x^2}\tag2\\&=\left[\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}}x\right]^2\tag3\\&=\left[\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2x}\right]^2\tag4\\&=\frac14\left[\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}x-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{-x}-1}x\right]^2\tag5\\&=\frac14\left[\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}x-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{-x}\right]^2\tag6\\&=\left[\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}x\right]^2\tag7\\&=1^2=1\tag8\end{align}$$

Thus,

> $$2L=1\implies L=\frac12$$

---

Steps:

$(1):$ Simply $(e^x-1-x)+(e^{-x}-1+x)=e^x+e^{-x}-2$

$(2):$ Turns out to be a perfect square.  Who knew?  ;)

$(3):$ We can take the square out.

$(4):$ Let $x\mapsto2x$.

$(5):$ Factor out the $1/2$ (which gets squared) and then split the limit into two, using: $e^x-e^{-x}=(e^x-1)-(e^{-x}-1)$.

$(6):$  Let $x\mapsto-x$ in the second limit.

$(7):$ Combine the resulting limits into one.

$(8):$ Use the well-known and probably given that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}x=1$.

Comment: You  used $\lim_0\frac {e^x-1}{x}=1$.

Comment: What is $L$ in your first step?

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Yes?

Comment: @Janitha357 $L$ is the limit, given by$$L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt How did you know that it existed?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Step 8 is Taylor or l'Hospital.

Comment: @Janitha357 Presumptuously :-) A formal proof of the existence of the limit can be managed easily through series, which more or less amount to applying the MVT.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Both of those are circular ways to find $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}x$.  This limit is usually given as the definition of $e$, or follows from the definition of $e$.

Comment: SHOOT.  I forgot I was only supposed to give out hints!  Oh well... I mean, not quite sure how to formulate this into a hint anyways...

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Neat (+1). The last step could be also done by using [$\,e^x \ge 1+x\,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504663/simplest-or-nicest-proof-that-1x-le-ex) which has several proofs that are light on calculus. Then squeeze $\,x \le e^x - 1 \le x /(1-x)\,$ around $\,x = 0\,$.

Comment: @dxiv What definition of $e^x$ do you happen to be using? :-)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt For $\,e^x \ge 1+x\,$ it's enough to use $\,e^x = \lim (1+x/n)^n\,$ plus Bernoulli's.

Comment: Fair enough (though I still think limits such as the one I used should be taken as givens for these sorts of questions)

Comment: One approach is to use the definition $e^{x} =\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^{n}$ and show that the limit in question for $x\to 0^{+}$ is $1/2$. The case $x\to 0^{-}$ can be deduced from the case of $x\to 0^{+}$ by using $e^{x} e^{-x} =1$.

Comment: See this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1565665/72031

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Use the Taylor Series expansion of $e^{x}$, then expand and cancel like-terms.